# make rectangular image appear circular with CSS without making pictures look out of shape

Tags: html, image, css

each post on my page has a picture and i want to make rectangular image appear circular, doing code below i get the effect, but the image looks out of shape: What can I do to fix this?

```
#circular img {
    width: 280px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    margin:35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of a random image:

[image: Image screenshot]

Comment: You have to start with a SQUARE.

Comment: Its because you have skewed the aspect. Keep the image as it is or crop then you can round the borders.

Answer (score 3):

One of options is to use image as a background and set it like this

https://jsfiddle.net/jL5ek6e8/

```
<div class="circle" style="background-image:url(http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/joke-battles/images/4/40/18360-doge-doge-simple.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20151209161638)"></div>

.circle {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-position:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

### edit

and besides that, why are you putting `background` property on an `img` tag?

Comment: I think you can also use an <img> inside your div, and add overflow:hidden. Could be usefull if you want to print the page, of just for SEO reasons.

Comment: @PierreGranger yup, you are right, but this is more secure way, when you have image way bigger than given circle, or way too small. You have to play with `min-width` and `min-height` and such in order to make this work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a square set  `border-radius: 50%;`

```
#circular  {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
        margin:35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't control the image proportions (e.g. from another site or user uploaded) you could use the `clip-path` property:

http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/YwJqQR

```
.clip {
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  clip-path: circle(250px at center);
}
```

Note that browser support is not perfect yet:

http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

You could also solve this with full cross browser support by using a background image with border radius, however this might not work for you for accessibility reasons.